# How to retrive widget title/data

Tags: widgets

I'm using this code to display widgets of certain sidebar:

```
$sidebar_id = 'sidebar1';
$sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
$widget_ids = $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id]; 
    foreach( $widget_ids as $id ) {
    echo '<li><a href="#'.$id.'">'.$id['title'].'</a></li>';
}
```

I'm trying to display the widget title using `$id['title']`, but It's not working.

Comment: Is your goal to only get the widgets from a specific sidebar or you just want to be able to grab widgets in general and show them?

Comment: The codex also says the functions you're using aren't intended to be used by developers other than core developers - that may be part of the issue: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sidebars_widgets

Comment: So, do you know about any function to retrieve widget data which as stored as $instance['name']?

Answer (score 3):

Found a 'dirty' way to do it:

Here's my code:

```
$sidebar_id = 'sidebar1';
$sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
$widget_ids = $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_id]; 
    foreach( $widget_ids as $id ) {
        $wdgtvar = 'widget_'._get_widget_id_base( $id );
        $idvar = _get_widget_id_base( $id );
        $instance = get_option( $wdgtvar );
        $idbs = str_replace( $idvar.'-', '', $id );
        echo '<li><a href="#'.$id.'">'.$instance[$idbs]['title'].'</a></li>';
    }
```

Comment: Glad you solved it Ahmed! Please mark this answer as accepted so it doesn't show as an unsolved question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just display all the widgets coming from a specific sidebar, try [dynamic_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar). Example taken from the Codex:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you're trying to get a specific widget and display it, try [the_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget#Examples_2). This example is taken from the Categories widget:

```
<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Links'); ?>
```

If neither of these help, you may have to provide us some more details as to what you're trying to do for more answers. Good luck!

Comment: I only want to show the title of the widget; I have the widget ID and I want to display its title.

Comment: It looks like the_widget automatically displays the widget and you can manipulate the title with the $instance parameter, but you can't show just the title using this function. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_widget/ Is it that you want titles only and no widget content? Where is this being displayed? Perhaps depending on your goal, there is another way to go about it.