# Get widget Title from widget id

Tags: widgets, title, id

Is there anyway at all to get the title of a widget from the widget id? The post title can be used by using

```
get_the_title()
```

Is there a way to get the title for a widget using the same kind or function?

Comment: [retrive widget title/data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170619/how-to-retrive-widget-title-data)

Comment: Not even close to what I'm wanting

Comment: I don't know how are we suppose to help you this time around. Seems like the above link contains the necessary logic of getting the meta data of the widget.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the widget name from the widget id with this:

```
<?php
    global $wp_registered_widgets;
    $id = 'recent-comments-1';  // example
    if ( isset($wp_registered_widgets[$id]['name']) ) {
        echo $wp_registered_widgets[$id]['name'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the `dynamic_sidebar_params`:

```php
/**
 *  Get Widget instance title or widget name as a fallback.
 *  Returns empty widget titles too.
 *
 *  @param string $widget_id
 *  @return string Widget title or widget name
 */
function get_widget_title( $widget_id ) {

    global $wp_registered_widgets;

    // get instance
    $instance = $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['callback'][0];
    // @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/get_settings/
    $settings = $instance->get_settings();

    // fallback 1 – widget number can't be found
    if ( isset( $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['params'][0]['number'] ) ) {
        $num = $wp_registered_widgets[$widget_id]['params'][0]['number'];
    } else {
        return $instance->name;
    }

    // nasty nesting
    if ( isset( $settings[ $num ]['title'] ) ) {
        return $settings[ $num ]['title'];
    }
    return $instance->name;

}
```